# Legume-based pasta and phytohaemagglutinin

Tags: food-safety, food-science

Most legume-based pasta specify a cook time of fewer than 10 minutes. Is that sufficient to deactivate the phytohaemagglutinin?
I initially thought that the bean flour may have been precooked before being formed into pasta, so to confirm this, I contacted one of the manufacturers (Tolerant Foods) and they replied "our raw material is **not** precooked."

Comment: What beans are they made from? Only a few have enough phytohaemagglutinin to matter; others don't need significant amounts of boiling.

Comment: Lord, you had me thinking soy bean root nodules- Nitrogenase and Leghemoglobin. Depending on the beans, I'd be concerned. Lectins can be pretty tough. Perhaps the lugumes have been pre-soaked rather than pre-cooked. That can be pretty effective.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, phytohaemagglutinin should be mostly present in red kidney beans or fava beans. (from wikipedia and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3153292/)

I looked at Tolerant Food product list on their web site and they only use lentils (red and green) and Chickpea products.

So, you should be good; but in any cases, if you feel unsafe, don't eat them.

Comment: Fava beans (aka broad beans) have much less than kidney beans, 5-10%, you can eat them raw without any problems, although they are must tastier cooked.